# Force Resolution on headless computer to view it when connecting remotely

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, headless

I have an headless windows 10 professional pc. Every time I connect to it with Solarwinds Take Control I get a resolution of 640x480. I tried to change the resolution with several tools but I can't make it. for example Qres.exe is telling me: "graphic mode is not supperted!"

Is there a way to force the resolution? From the default windows 10 settings is impossible since I view the desktop at 640x480 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You use Solarwinds RMM and connect to a headless computer, you can choose to connect as RDP. The remote desktop protocol will then allow you to set the resolution you want. You have no other way to change resolution of the machine, only of the control session.